# SQL Server query for organization of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, sql-server, ajax

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I want to achieve this view thru database query and display it programmatically using jquery.

**Expected output**

[image]

**Current output**

[image]

This is my current query:

```
SELECT [OrganizationName],COUNT([Id]) AS Frequency,[Set] FROM *{table}* GROUP BY [Set],[OrganizationName];
```

And I display the table using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetOrganizations", "Companies")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: null,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("result length: " + result.length);
                $("#orgTableDiv").css("max-height", result.length * 15);
                if (result.length > 0 && result[0].OrganizationName!=null) 
                {
                    var selectOptions = "<option value='All'>All</option>"; // dropdown containing all organizations
                    $("#orgTable").empty();
                    var div = "";

                    div = "<tr>" +
                            "<th>No</th>" +
                            "<th>Organization Name</th>";

                    for (var i=0; i<data.length ; i++) {
                        div += "<th>"+data[i]["name"]+"</th>";
                    }

                    div += "</tr>";
                    $("#orgTable").append(div);

                    var numOfSets = data.length;
                    var organizationName = "";
                    var counter = 1;

                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                        var row = "<tr>" +
                                        "<td>" + counter + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + result[i].OrganizationName + "</td>";
                        if (result[i].SetValue!=null)
                            for (var j=0; j < result[i].SetValue.length; j++) {
                                var setData = result[i].SetValue[j].split(':');

                                for (var m=0; m<setData.length; m++) {
                                    var temp = setData;
                                }

                                var setNum = setData[0];
                                var setFrequency = setData[1];

                                for (var c=1; c<=numOfSets; c++) {
                                    if (c==setNum)
                                        row += "<td>" + setFrequency + "</td>";

                                }
                            }
                        counter++;
                        row += "</tr>";

                        $("#orgTable").append(row);
                        selectOptions +="<option value='" + result[i].OrganizationName+ "'>" + result[i].OrganizationName+ "</option>";
                    }

                    $('#organizationOption').empty().append(selectOptions);
                }

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Error: ' + result);
            }
        })
```

How can I achieve the expected output? I am currently stuck with my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [OrganizationName],
Sum(case when set = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as set1,
Sum(case when set = 2 then 1  else 0 end) as set2,
Sum(case when set = 3 then 1  else 0 end) as set3,
Sum(case when set = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as set4,

FROM *{table}* GROUP BY [OrganizationName];
```

The above query will give you the desired output

Comment: Akshey, frequency is not part of the table. It is the count of all the entries for organization for specific set

Comment: Modified answer check please

Comment: By the way, the set number may vary depending on the values in the Set column. Is there a way to make this dynamic?

Comment: You can look into dynamic SQL for this

Comment: Will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    select *
    from 
    (
      select OrganizationName, set, Frequency
      from Tablename
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      sum(Frequency)
      for set in ([1], [2], [3],[4])
    ) piv;
```

Comment: can you please share details y or what does not worked for you